# What genre is the music of Fetty Wap?

Tags: identify-this-genre, rap, trap

I know [Fetty Wap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fetty_Wap) is a rapper, but I also heard that there is some influence of trap in his music (there is a song called [*Trap Queen*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_kF4zLNKio)). What kind of genre is his music? Is there an official genre for this mix of rap and trap?

Comment: Hi. Did you find a satisfying answer below?

Comment: Hi. Yes, they are both helpful. Why do you ask? Especially after such a long time? I'm curious now...

Comment: I thought I could write an answer, but when I saw there were already two unaccepted answers I wanted to know it would worth it... but since these answers are good to you, that's OK :-)

Answer (score 3):

From this article http://masetv.com/fetty-wap-names-gucci-mane-as-influence-behind-his-ignorant-rb-music/ he refers to his music as "ignorant R&B"

The **Awards and nominations** chart below on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fetty_Wap#cite_note-42 shows that he received nominations for mainly HipHop and Rap, but this doesn't mean his music can't *also* include other sub-genre influences(i.e. trap). *Personally*, being a regular listener of his music, I consider him mainly trap.

Comment: The link to the article on masetv.com seems to be dead.

Answer (score 2):

There is always a way to create a new genre, or stretch the sub genres in general.
Look at metal for example, there are too many subgenres for everything.

Fetty Wap is what I would categorize as Hiphop/Rap with trap influences, nothing more or less to keep it simple.

Comment: could you say more on how the different elements in his music come from each bucket ? for those not familiar with the artist or genre, but curious.

Answer (score 1):

I think he's a trap rapper/singer because his latest album was named [Trap & B.](https://www.naijaprey.com.ng/tag/fetty-wap/)